# I am trying to get a dynamic value from the response data and use that dynamic value to pass in the url path so the next get method can use it

Tags: json, jmeter

I am new to jmeter
The response data is
[image]

I want to take contentId from the above response and pass it at the end of other get url path so as to get data which is under that content id and I have to use it for multiple users who have different contentId. So how could I dynamically pass it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response and configure it as follows:

   - name of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `contentId`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.contentId`

   [image]
2. That's it, in the next request path field just use `${contentId}` variable where required:

   [image]

More information:

- [JSONPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)
- [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Comment: Thank you I have tried it but I when I am comparing any 2 contentid's using beanshell assertion it's not failing,it has to fail as the values are different for two and even in the result request I can't see the used contentid in the url. Can you please help me with it.